# Linearizing a DDE about a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the delayed logistic equation

$$ N'(t)= rN(t) \left[1-\frac{1}{K} \int_0^\infty N(t-u)k(u) \> {du}\right]$$

where

$$k(u)= \frac{1}{\tau} \exp\left(\frac{-u}{\tau}\right)$$

linearized at $N=k$ is given by

$$n'(t)=-r \int_0^\infty n(t-u)k(u) \> du \>.$$

Following from an example, I understand that since we know there is a steady state of this equation at $N^*$ where $N^* =K$, we 'linearize' about the steady state defining

$$\begin{align} n &=N-N^* \\
&=N-K
\end{align}$$

but I don't know where to go from here. I wouldn't understand how to do the Taylor expansion about this point because of the integral.